# Undergrad question but with postgrad implications

Tags: discussion

I am referring to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11112/can-i-annex-fewer-certificates-for-a-shorter-application) about the application process - it is something that often happens for postgraduate, as well as undergraduate applications, so it could be useful for anyone reading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specified question is on-topic for German graduate students as well. I've posted a note to that effect on the question, and would therefore "overrule" a motion to close. (Granted it helps that I know the German system well enough, and someone else might not. However, the important thing is that it is relevant for the board.)

Comment: it has also been upvoted - so, is useful.

Comment: It appears that the question is now 'on hold', I have submitted to reopen.